# Passing Firebase data to another screen with React Navigation Tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-navigation

I want to pass Firebase data for a specific list item to another screen by onPress in a Flatlist. In the destination screen I want to display the Firebase data for the item selected in a  field and use a button or switch to mark the item as 'complete' and save that response to Firebase. I thought that it would be best to use the ComponentDidMount in the first 'List' screen rendered to get all the data and reuse it on the other screen.

The questions are:
(1) How do I display the Flatlist data from Firebase in List.js on the Detail screen?

(2) Should I use the ComponentDidMount in List.js to get all the information that I will pass to the Detail screen (not all is displayed in the list)? If I shouldn't, how do I get the extra information in the Detail screen, as I got error with a ComponentDidMount in that screen as well as in the List.js screen.

(3) How do I remove Details from the 'Pages' Tab Navigator and only access it by selecting a line in the Flatlist? But how? When I remove it the Flatlist items don't go to another screen with onPress.

List.js - I input data from Firebase and present it in a Flatlist.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  const keyParent =       firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/Profile`);

    keyParent.on(('child_added'), snapshot => {
      const newChild = {
           key: snapshot.key,
           color: snapshot.val().color,
           enddate: snapshot.val().enddate
           other: snapshot.val().other //to display on destination screen only
           other2: snapshot.val().other2 //to display on destination screen only
      };
       
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ list: [...prevState.list, newChild] }));

  });
}
```

List.js - This is the render.item section of the Flatlist and my attempt to navigate to the Detail screen with the data from Firebase. The params section is not working, as I'm unsure how to reference the data from Firebase.

```js
onRenderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSeeDetail}>
    <Text style={styles.listStyle}>
        { item.color }{'\n'}
        { item.enddate }
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

onSeeDetail = () => {
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Details',
  params: { key: this.key, colour: 'texttest', enddate: this.enddate, other: this.other, other2: this.other2 },
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}
```

Here is the navigation portion in App.js

```js
renderContent() {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      case true:
        return <Pages />;
      case false:
        return <AuthTabs />;
      default:
        return <Spinner size="large" />;
    }
  }
```

Navigate.js

```js
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Register, Login, Add, List, Logout, Details } from './screens';

export const ListStack = StackNavigator({

  List: {
    screen: List,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'List',
      },
  },
  Details: {
    screen: Details,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Details',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'white',
      activeBackgroundColor: 'blue',
      inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
      inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        padding: 10
      },
    }
});

export const Pages = TabNavigator({
  List: {
    screen: List,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'List',
    },
  },
  Add: {
    screen: Add,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Add',
    },
  },
    Details: {
    screen: Details,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Details',
    },
  },
  Logout: {
    screen: Logout,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Log Out',
    },
  },
},
  {
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'white',
            activeBackgroundColor: 'blue',
            inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 20,
              padding: 10
            },
    }
});

export const AuthTabs = TabNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Log In',
    },
  },
  Register: {
    screen: Register,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Sign Up',
    },
  },
},
  {
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'white',
            activeBackgroundColor: 'blue',
            inactiveTintColor: 'blue',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 20,
              padding: 10
            },
    }
});
```